how to display text with nextline, space in flex and tailwind CSS
There are several lines text with dot. I tried to use whitespace-pre-line, but it didn't work.
This is the code


<div className="flex items-center group" >
    <p
       className="px-6 py-3 rounded-b-lg rounded-r-lg bg-gray-800 w-[28rem] max-w-xs lg:max-w-md text-gray-200 whitespace-pre-line">
           Hello @Green 

           Greetings from VPN Infotech! We're thrilled about your positive experience with us. We're here to offer our expertise/ service as listed.

           • We recommend integrating AI into your existing website or mobile application to enhance its performance. 
           • Our team specializes in optimizing and quality assurance for your current web/mobile application, and we'll provide insights for upgrades and the implementation of new features in line with current trends. 
           • Additionally, we offer maintenance services to ensure the ongoing smooth operation of your web/mobile application.

Thank you for considering VPN Infotech; we're excited about the prospect of working together again.

Best regards.
      </p>



This is the result

I need to display text with nextline, space in flex and tailwind CSS

The context is a little bit unclear. Did you mean that the dot will put a sentence in the next line?

No,  current text has space next line and dots.. I want to display in html with same style.

Are you fetching or scraping the text (dynamic text data) from an external source? I am wondering why you can't use the "p" tag along with the "ul" and "li" tags to construct the same result if you have control over the text content !

I can't use ul and li

It should actually work. See https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/VwOMvgB. Maybe there is some other CSS rule overriding the style or something wrong with you tailwind config

As per our conversation above, I would say that I do not fully understand what you actually need, but let's try.
Here is the proposed solution using ul and li
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto bg-white p-6 rounded shadow">
        <p>Hello @Green,</p>
        
        <p class="mt-4">
            Greetings from VPN Infotech! We're thrilled about your positive experience with us. We're here to offer our expertise/service as listed.
        </p>
        
        <ul class="list-disc pl-6 mt-4">
            <li>We recommend integrating AI into your existing website or mobile application to enhance its performance.</li>
            <li>Our team specializes in optimizing and quality assurance for your current web/mobile application, and we'll provide insights for upgrades and the implementation of new features in line with current trends.</li>
            <li>Additionally, we offer maintenance services to ensure the ongoing smooth operation of your web/mobile application.</li>
        </ul>
        
        <p class="mt-4">
            Thank you for considering VPN Infotech; we're excited about the prospect of working together again.
        </p>
        
        <p class="mt-4">Best regards,</p>
    </div>


and here is another one without li and ul
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto bg-white p-6 rounded shadow space-y-4">
        <p>Hello @Green,</p>
        
        <p>
            Greetings from VPN Infotech! We're thrilled about your positive experience with us. We're here to offer our expertise/service as listed.
        </p>
        
        <p class="pl-4">• We recommend integrating AI into your existing website or mobile application to enhance its performance.</p>
        <p class="pl-4">• Our team specializes in optimizing and quality assurance for your current web/mobile application, and we'll provide insights for upgrades and the implementation of new features in line with current trends.</p>
        <p class="pl-4">• Additionally, we offer maintenance services to ensure the ongoing smooth operation of your web/mobile application.</p>
        
        <p>
            Thank you for considering VPN Infotech; we're excited about the prospect of working together again.
        </p>
        
        <p>Best regards,</p>
    </div>

